# How do I use xStream to output Java Objects with List properties?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, xstream

I am trying to output some Java objects as JSON, they have List properties which I want to be formatted as  { "People" : [ { "Name" : "Bob" } , { "Name" : "Jim" } ] }

However, I cannot figure out how to do this with XStream. It always outputs as { "Person" : { "Name" : "Bob" }, "Person" : { "Name" : "Bob" }

Is there a way to fix this? I've put together some sample code with a unit test in github if you need something more concrete to play with: http://gist.github.com/371358

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the problem is with **@XStreamImplicit** which is declared on top of the List, remove that and try. It should work fine ;)

/jay